# I want to add tooltip text on a label "fieldtype" in Extjs only if the text of the "fieldlabel" is "Periods"

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add tooltip text on a label "fieldtype" in Extjs only if the text of the "fieldlabel" is "Periods" .How can this be implemented in EXtjs.
Can I use If else directly?

Comment: may you provide fiddle sample?

Answer (score 0):

tooltips are not available for form field labels.  Other than buttons I am not sure if there are any other components you can add a tooltip to.